# Ionic 2 Angularfire2 and Firebase item to array

Tags: arrays, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2, ngfor

I want to add firebase observable list to variable array in ionic2

I query my template with service :

```
getModel(model){

    let modelQuery = this.afo.database.list(this.currentUser.username + '/models', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'name',
            equalTo: model
        }
    });

    return modelQuery;
}
```

I call `getModel` service in my ts :

```
this.character = navParams.get('character');
this.currentUser = modelService.currentUser;
this.models = modelService.models;
this.model = modelService.getModel(this.character.model);
this.items = this.model;
```

and I parse data in my page :

```
<ion-item  *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{ item?.items | json }}
</ion-item>
```

and the result is :

[image: result]

my firebase :

[image]

my problem is :

I want add to this observable list in my item variable like an array.
When I use `ngfor` for my items I have an inline result with objects in an array

```
[
{
  "name": "description",
  "rows": "3",
  "type": "ion-textarea"
},
{
  "name": "toggle",
  "type": "ion-toggle"
},
{
  "max": 100,
  "min": 0,
  "name": "range test",
  "type": "ion-range",
  "value": 0
},
{
  "max": 80,
  "min": 0,
  "name": "range 2",
  "type": "ion-range",
  "value": 0
},
{
  "max": 50,
  "min": 0,
  "name": "range 3",
  "type": "ion-range",
  "value": 0
},
{
  "name": "azeazraze",
  "type": "ion-input"
},
{
  "name": "ertefer",
  "type": "ion-title"
},
{
  "name": "ghg",
  "type": "ion-title"
}
]
```

so I want to add this array in my variable item to show with an `ngfor`.

Comment: you mean you want to _show_ ionic components in template based on your arraylist?

Comment: yes, i want take chikd node on firebase /user/model/items and show it like an array

Comment: You will have to make an elaborate template with _a lot of_ `*ngIf`s. Ionic  does not have any real support for server side rendering of templates..if that is what you require

Answer (score 1):

```
A small modification to your query to get items array. 

 getModelItems ( model ) {

    let items = []

    let modelQuery = this.afo.database.list(this.currentUser.username + '/models', {

      query: {
        orderByChild: 'name',
        equalTo: model
      }
    }).subscribe(models => {
      items = [];
      models.forEach(model => {
        items.push(model.items);
      })
    });

    console.log("model query");
    console.log(modelQuery);
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[code]getModel(model){

let modelQuery = this.afo.database.list(this.currentUser.username + '/models'     , {

query: {
       orderByChild: 'name',
       equalTo: model

```
 }}).map((items) => {
   return items.map(item => {
     item.data = this.afo.database.list(this.currentUser.username + `/models/${model.items}` );
     console.log("item",item); 

     return   item; //need this data item in variable
   })
 })
```

return modelQuery

}[/code]

i use this map, so i need to retrieve this data.item to my page